# C# public class new element

Tags: c#

I start in C # programming. I hope for help

I have a public class

```
namespace Character
{
  public class Character
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
  }
}
```

It is located in the file Characters.cs

In another file, I write variables to this class:

```
Character.Character character = new Character.Character
    {
      Name = CharacterController.LoadCharacterData(player).Result[0].Name,
      Surname = CharacterController.LoadCharacterData(player).Result[0].Surname
    };
```

But already when data is received in the third file, it is empty.

```
Character.Character character = new Character.Character();
string formatName = character.Name + " " + character.Surname;
```

Most likely, when I create a new class, it is emptied. But how then can I call separate variables from the class, because it did not work out for me:

```
Character.Character.Name;
```

Comment: Keep learning from tutorials.  Really, that's your next step here.  You're creating a *new instance* of the class.  Values you stored in *one* instance are not available in *another* instance.  As an analogy, consider a car.  You got a new car off the assembly line, and you put something in its trunk.  You then get another car off the assembly line.  It's *identical in every way* to the first one.  When you open the second car's trunk, do you expect to find the thing you put in the first car's trunk?

Comment: On a side note [Do not name a class the same as its namespace, Part One](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is empty not because the class is 'emptied' when you create it here:

```
Character.Character character = new Character.Character();
string formatName = character.Name + " " + character.Surname;
```

Its just a new instance of that class, its supposed to be empty.

To call a variable from anywhere within a file I always make it global to that file. eg.:

**The constructor of the class/form/whatnot you need your character in:**

```
Character.Character ActiveCharacter;    
//Now I can use my ActiveCharacter all over 'SomeForm'
public SomeForm( Character.Character character )
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ActiveCharacter = character;
}
```

**How to call this class/form:**

```
//This is my main form, I made a character here and want to pass it along for use
Character.Character char = new Character.Character();
char.Name = "EpicKip";

SomeForm someForm = new SomeForm(char);//Pass character as parameter
someForm.Show();//Useless if not form
```

And to explain a class and why a new one is empty:

Lets say you get 2 puppies, you name puppy 1 to 'Dex'. Puppy 2 remains nameless as of now because its a different puppy. Just like your character was a 2nd "different" instance.

Comment: @Joseph If you are using 1 and the same character in all files I would indeed pass it to the third file in the constructor and set a global instance of it.

Answer (score 4):

The idea of a `new SomeClass()` is that *each instance* has different values - you can have lots of different `Character`s. You have two choices:

- make the *specific* instance available to the code that needs it - usually be passing the object reference around
- if the data **doesn't represent** something that is instance specific, you could make the members (and perhaps the entire type) `static` - then you don't need to cite a particular instance, but: *there will only ever will one set of values at a time*

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of your class. The values you put in one instance are not "carried over" to a different/another instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every time you call `new Character.Character()` a new instance of the class will be created.

So in the second case `Character.Character character = new Character.Character();` you create a new instance without any properties set.

What you want is to pass your instance to your third file.

```
// method in third file
public static string FormatName(Character.Character instance) {
    return $"{instance.Name} {instance.Surname}";
}

// instantition and usage in second file
Character.Character character = new Character.Character {
    Name = CharacterController.LoadCharacterData(player).Result[0].Name,
    Surname = CharacterController.LoadCharacterData(player).Result[0].Surname
};

var formated = FormatName(character);
```

Note that you could also create a getter in your Character class to provide the formated name, instead of creating a method that accepts Character .

```
public class Character {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string FormatedName => $"{Name} {Surname}";
}
```

and call this on an instance with

```
var formated = character.FormatedName; // call on instance of character
```